# Flask set Authentication-Header in Bearer Format

Tags: python, authentication, flask

I'm using FLASK to authenticate with Keycloak. When I use `resp.set_cookie('jwt_token', jwt_token)` in every request is now a Cookie with `jwt_token=....`.

But I need the token in a Header as a bearer Token.

is there a way to add a header like a Cookie for future requests?

```py
@app.route(f'/{url}/callback')
def callback():
    auth_code = request.args.get('code')
    token_params = {
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'code': auth_code,
        'client_id': keycloak_client_id,
        'client_secret': keycloak_client_secret,
        'redirect_uri': keycloak_redirect_uri.format(rd=request.args.get('rd').replace('/', '%2F'))
    }

    response = requests.post(keycloak_token_endpoint, data=token_params)


    if response.status_code == 200:
        token_data = response.json()
        print(token_data)
        token_data = response.json()

        jwt_token = token_data.get('access_token')

        resp = redirect(f'{redirect_host}/{request.args.get("rd").replace("%2F", "/")}')
        resp.set_cookie('jwt_token', jwt_token)

        return resp
    else:
        return "Authentifizierung fehlgeschlagen"
```

EDIT1: I don't use any frontend app. I want to access the site with a browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Flask-JWT-extended, you can accept JWT tokens from the cookies as well as accepting them through the Bearer Token authorization headers. Since you are not using any front-end logic to continually pass the authorization header, it is easier to set/unset persistent cookies.

```
app.config["JWT_TOKEN_LOCATION"] = ["headers", "cookies"]
```

You may want to look into the Flask-JWT-extended docs: https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/token_locations.html

The full example using Flask-JWT-extended is below:

```
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, url_for, jsonify
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager, jwt_required, create_access_token, set_access_cookies, unset_jwt_cookies, get_jwt_identity
        
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'a secret key'
app.config['JWT_SECRET_KEY'] = 'another secret key'
app.config["JWT_TOKEN_LOCATION"] = ["headers", "cookies"]
app.config["JWT_COOKIE_CSRF_PROTECT"] = False
        
jwt = JWTManager(app)
        
@jwt.expired_token_loader
def my_expired_token_callback(jwt_header, jwt_payload):
    response = redirect(url_for('login'))
    unset_jwt_cookies(response)
    flash('Login session has expired. Please login again.', 'error')
    return response
        
@jwt.invalid_token_loader
def my_invalid_token_callback(jwt_header, jwt_payload):
    response = redirect(url_for('login'))
    unset_jwt_cookies(response)
    flash('Invalid token. Please login again.', 'error')
    return response
        
@jwt.unauthorized_loader
def my_unauthorized_token_callback(jwt_payload):
    response = redirect(url_for('login'))
    flash('Please login to access this page.', 'error')
    return response
    
@app.route("/login", methods=["POST"])
def login():
    response = jsonify({"msg": "login successful"})
    access_token = create_access_token(identity="example_user")
    set_access_cookies(response, access_token)
    return response 
      
@app.route("/protected")
@jwt_required()
def protected():
    user_jwt = get_jwt_identity()
    return 'Accessed Protected Route Successfully'
```